Why is the matrix representation of CNOT gate valid
$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\newline 0&1&0&0\newline 0&0&0&1\newline 0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$
Obviously, given any $4\times 1$ matrix, it fixes the first two number and swap the second two numbers. Which means, for any $|ab\rangle$ where $a,b\in\{0,1\}$, b is always inverted. That's not as decribed what a controled not gate should do.

That's not how it works. I think you're misunderstanding what the tensor product of two states looks like. $|00\rangle = (1,0,0,0)^T$ and $|01\rangle = (0,1,0,0)^T$, so CNOT on these states does nothing. Meanwhile, $|10\rangle = (0,0,1,0)^T$ and $|11\rangle = (0,0,0,1)^T$, so CNOT will interchange these two.

Downvoters - why? The questioner had some misunderstandings but that's why the question was asked. It could have been better, or more artfully worded - e.g., if the post had said "What is my misunderstanding about the CNOT matrix?" then certainly downvotes would have been far from justified.  But even the present wording doesn't justify as many dv's IMHO.

As correctly pointed out in the comments, the matrix doesn't operate in the way you described.
CNOT is a quantum conditional, similar to a classical conditional like if-then-else. The implementation of a quantum conditional operator is done by a quantum multiplexor [Shende et. al.]. When the multiplexor has only a single bit for 'control' that determines what unitary operation needs to be executed on the 'target' bit, the multiplexor has the following block diagonal form:
$$ U = \begin{pmatrix}U_0 & 0 \\ 0 & U_1\end{pmatrix} $$
To clarify, $U_0$ will be implemented on the target bit if the most significant bit is 0, or $U_1$ is implemented if it is 1.
Now, returning to the case of CNOT which is a simplest case of a quantum muliplexor,
$$ CNOT = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} $$

It implements the unitary $U_0 = I$, keeping the target bit as it is, if the control bit is 0
else implements $U_1 = X$ resulting in a bit flip for the target bit, if the control bit is 1.

I hope this helps.
